# How to get current file offset in Vim

Tags: vim

I see that I can easily get the size of the screen in Vim like this:

```
:echo &lines . ' ' . &columns
```

How do I get the current offset of the file I am viewing.
For example, if I am scrolled down and the line number of the first row is 100, what variable or function would give me 100?

Is there a list somewhere of all these variables/functions?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `line()` and `col()` functions with an argument of `'.'` (which means use the current location):

```
:echo line('.') . ' ' . col('.')
```

You can find the list of available functions [here](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#functions).  Note: this does change with versions of Vim.  Also, there is a list of variables [here](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#internal-variables).